# error C2039 : 'WaitForSingleObject' is not a member of 'boost::detail::win32'

Tags: c++, mongodb, winapi, boost, visual-studio-2013

I'm tryging to install c++ mongo driver but when I try to build it with scons I get the following error \util\concurrency\shared_mutex_win.hpp(180) : error C2039 : 'WaitForSingleObject' is not a member of 'boost::detail::win32'.
Please one to help me in fixing the problem. I have included windows.h header in the required position, but yet not working. I'm running windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio 2013 ultimate.

[image: The command prompt screen shot of the build]

Comment: Just a guess - have you put `using namespace` in any header file?

Comment: No, I didn't put 'using namespace' anywhere. I'm using boost 1.59.0, scons 2.1.0

Comment: Don't paste diagnostic output as screenshots. Screenshots escape text searches, making this question less discoverable, i.e. less useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fixEd it by removing the scope resolution operators used with the thread methods calls in the shared_mutex_win.hpp file. That is, boost::detail::WaitForSingleObject becomes WaitForSingleObject and boost::detail::WaithForMultipleObjects becomes WaithForMultipleObjects. 
I hope this will help someone subsequently.

Comment: Modifying 3rd party library code is not ever a solution for any problem.

Comment: @steadybits Yeah, you really shouldn't need to do that. What version of the MongoDB driver are you trying to install? It looks like 26compat or legacy. Is there a reason you aren't using the newer C++11 driver from the master branch? Also, if you want help with this, please update your question with the information described here about how to ask for help with the 26compat/legacy driver: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver#how-to-ask-for-help